# SQL: delete only if subquery (containing 0, 1, or more rows) equals scalar value

Tags: sql, h2

### Description

I'm trying to do something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM ...
-- `<my_id>` is any given long scalar value
WHERE <my_id> = (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE ...);
```

That syntax is not entirely correct. If the select subquery contains more than one row, then we get an error like:

> Scalar subquery contains more than one row

However, my intended purpose is indeed:

- if the subquery returns exactly 1 value equal to the scalar value (`<my_id>`) ==> delete
- else (0, or 2 or more values, or 1 non-equal value) ==> do not delete (ignore)

### Question

I do not want neither `IN` nor `EXISTS`. I need rather something like "equals", which can compare a scalar value against possibly multi-valued rows.

What is the syntax in SQL for that?

### Stack

In particular, I'm testing this with H2.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thanks Gordon 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
DELETE FROM ...
WHERE <my_id> IN (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE ...) AND
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM . . . WHERE . . .) = 1;
```

However, this is more simply written as:

```
DELETE FROM ...
WHERE <my_id> = (SELECT MAX(id)
                 FROM . . . 
                 WHERE . .  
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                ) ;
```

If the count is not `1`, then the subquery returns nothing and there is no match (so nothing is deleted).

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I had `HAVING` missing in my SQL vocabulary. Since we are checking that we only have one row with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`, I guess using `MAX` is just a kind of trick. We just need some aggregation function, and, for instance, `MIN`, in this case, would work exactly the same as `MAX`... right?

Comment: @juanmirocks . . . Exactly.  If there is one row, then `MIN()` and `MAX()` return the same value.